# jQuery/JS simulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not an expert in jQuery or Javascript (I have only started with it recently), so this might sound like a silly question:
I have 4 tabs, all of which are clickable. So, I made 2 functions, 1 to actually execute on click, and one to only "simulate" the click, so I could change the tabs every 5 seconds. What I've done is, set a bool variable "click" to false, which is set to "true" if the actualy click function is executed, so the automatic tab switching stops. And below both of these functions I added a while loop like this:

```
var nr = 0;
while(!klik){
    tabss.eq(st % 4).click().delay(5000); //this is the "simulation"
    st++;
}
```

now, it opens up the first tab as it's suppose to, but after 5 seconds nothing happens. Any suggestions? I sorta want is like a slideshow that stops, when users clicks something.

Comment: Should `st` be `nr` instead? Also, that while loop is going to be a performance buster: you're delaying a click function for 5 seconds, but your calling `click()` as fast as your CPU will let you.

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI Tabs, there is a built-in rotate action  that's very easy to set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.delay` is only to be used with jQuery animations. What you need to use is `setTimeout` or `setInterval`:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (!klik) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        st %= 4;
        clickontab($tabs.eq(st++));
    }
}, 5000); // milliseconds

$('div.tab').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    klik = false;
    clickontab(this);
});

function clickontab(tab) {
    // code to bring a particular tab to the front
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/CDNXv/2/

Comment: I was just typing up almost an identical answer :-(. I would like to add that Ben Alman has his jQuery doTimeout plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) which may offer more features and whatnot.

Comment: Great, that works with the rotation, but it won't stop. When I click a tab, it will still rotate forward. But no worries, probably something on my part with setting the 'klik' variable

Comment: @GregaMenih In my original jsfiddle, the `setInterval` triggers the same click handler that is triggered when the user clicks. I've updated my answer with a modified solution to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest this method :

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(openTab,4000);

function openTab(){
   if(i>4) i=0;
   tabss.eq(i).click();
   i++;

}
```